# How do I share a papyrus project via git?

Tags: eclipse, git, share, papyrus

I have modelled some diagrams using the papyrus eclipse plugin. I want to share them in my git repository, so my coworkers can see and modify them.
I simply copied all files to the repository.
They can now all see the files in the repository, but when they open them in their eclipse,
they only see a blank space.
How do you do this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue until 5 minutes ago. Tell to your coworkers to open the "Papyrus" perspective and double-click on the papyrus file, now go to the "model explorer" view, open the three and double-click on the last element, from now coworkers can open the model from the main file in the project explorer view.

I hope this solution works also for you, sorry for my english.

Comment: with tears in my eyes I thank god for your answer, sir! god bless you!